# Clang linker error 'symbol(s) not found' calling function declared in common header

Tags: c++, xcode, linker, xcode5

This is my first time using header files, I decided I should learn how. Unfortunately, I'm already stuck...

In a.cpp:

```
#include "common.h"

int aFunction(){
    bFunction();

    return 0;
}
```

In b.cpp:

```
#include "common.h"

int bFunction(){
    return 0;
}
```

In common.h:

```
using namespace std;

#ifndef __bFunction
#define __bFunction
int bFunction();
#endif

#ifndef __aFunction
#define __aFunction
int aFunction();
#endif
```

Error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "bFunction()", referenced from:
      aFunction() in main-0788bc.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you linking `main.o` against `a.o` and `b.o`?

Comment: Erm.. well `main.cpp` has `#include "main.h"`, and `main.h` has `#include "common.h"` if that's what you mean?

Comment: Not exactly, it seems the issue is related to the linking process. If `bFunction()` is defined in `b.o`, you need to link against it. Google for it.

Comment: I tried to Google before, and tried again with 'cpp link against object file' like you suggest, but i just can't find anything - I don't really know enough about it to know what to look for.. Could you give me a basic example?